# Is it possible to add notes to an rmarkdown html document AFTER knitting?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am knitting a html markdown file for a customer with plenty of interactive visualizations inside it.

My client - not a tech user - would like to add their own comments, conclusions to the document, and using it for a presentation.

Is it possible to add a text box to an rmarkdown html document that can be edited and saved by a non-technical user?

What alternatives I have to keep the document interactive but editable after knitting?

I would like to avoid the case that the customer just copies screenshots from my html and pastes into a ppt.

Comment: If you wanted to use `shiny` you could keep it interactive. However, you have to keep it running with some type of background. For example, you could make a `shiny` app. (This can be done with or without R Markdown.)

Comment: Deploying a shiny app is not an option, thank you. For that I need a backend server, authentication (data is sensitive), and and still not resolved my root problem: make my client able to add comments next to visualizations.

Comment: If you want non-technical editing, printing to Word is one way to go. Or your client could open the HTML document in Word or another WYSIWYG HTML editor. A quick hack might be a textarea box.

Comment: @BálintKomjáti, consider this: an Rmd file is rendered into one of several formats. Assuming non-`shiny`, none of the remaining are "interactive", they render a relatively static document (HTML with javascript notwithstanding). This means for the most part: Word, PowerPoint, PDF, or HTML. The ability to add comments to any of them will have nothing to do with R, since by definition the commenting will be on a static "standard" document. The exception is if you can find a javascript library that does what you want (I don't know of any) that allows them to comment and send comments to you.

Comment: Ultimately, I can relate to the question (as we discussed it a few years ago), but we resolved that if somebody wants to comment on a PDF I sent them, then they need a PDF editor (nothing to do with R). If they need to be able to edit/comment and they don't have a PDF editor, then I would need to export to Word (docx), and they would then comment/edit as needed. This is as dash2 already said, and I think there's very little more that can be done in an R (and [tag:r]-tag) context.

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal experience, I think you can add text commenting feature on the Rmd by uploading it to a Github page. You may follow this guidance on how to do so:
https://www.smaranyadey.com/post/creating-r-markdown-documents-and-publishing-them-using-github-pages

After the Github page set up, you can add widget like *[Hypothes.is](https://Hypothes.is)* which enable your client to annotate as well as highlight some texts.
You can make the Github page private so only your client can access your Rmd.

**UPDATE:**

Gosh, I just foud very simpler way to embed the Hypothesis script to the HTML output without the need for uploading to Github Page.

Just put this code under YAML:

```
---    
<script src="https://hypothes.is/embed.js" async></script>
```

This update refers to an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817937/rmarkdown-generated-html-document-notes-comments-pane?rq=1)